# Chrome (and Edge) asking several mic permissions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

In my page I have three audio recorders. And when chrome asks permission to use the mic, it has the options: "allow", "block" and to close the permission popup.

If the use closes de popup, it appears other permission, and after that another (if the user repeats the action). One for each recorder.

Is there a way to show this only one time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was using [react-media-recorder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-media-recorder), I tried to see if it was a bug in the lib. And it happened that the recorder was asking permission on mounting.

I changed this to ask only when the user click to record.

So if anyone has the same problem (even if you don't use this lib) try the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple microphones or cameras, you can choose which one to use as the default device for chrome.
Follow these steps: Open Chrome -> `settings` -> `Privacy and security` -> `Site Settings` -> `Microphone` -> Choose the microphone you need to use

Open Chromium Edge -> `settings` -> `cookies and site permissions` -> `Microphone` -> `Choose which microphone the browser can access`

Or you can set whether to allow the use of the microphone for each website, through the site settings on this page.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for a general solution for all visitor of the page. That if they close the popup that it won’t show a second and third time.

Comment: I think you may be using [getUserMedia() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Build_a_phone_with_peerjs/Connect_peers/Get_microphone_permission) to get user permissions.
If this is the case, I think it is impossible. The pop-up window is controlled by the user's browser settings, and the authorized operation is performed by the user. If the operation can be controlled by script code, it will involve browser security issues. If possible, you can use only one recorder.